# Why DataGridViewComboBoxColumn displays ValueMember?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hi I have the following code in C#

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn nameColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
nameColumn.DataPropertyName = "Name";
nameColumn.ReadOnly = false;
nameColumn.DataSource = getNamesAndIds();
nameColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";
nameColumn.ValueMember = "Ids";
m_dataGrid.Columns.Insert(i++, nameColumn);
```

Basically I have a gridview which displays student's name and their info. Users should be able to change the values in the cells and then update database.

After I retrieve data from database, they are displayed well on the grid view. However, when I want to update a cell in the name column, **the cell displays Ids instead of the name I select.**

Any help?

Comment: Please explain your question a lot better.

Comment: what kind of data `getNamesAndIds` returns?

Comment: getNamesAndIds() returns a DataTable with 2 columns, Name and Id